# No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

I am trying to implement WEBFLUX with kotlin. But with a simple GET API, I am getting the below exceptions -
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest
at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.java:220) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE] Exception while invoking the following GET Api -

```kotlin
@GetMapping(value = ["/dmm/health"], produces = arrayOf(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
    fun dmmHealth(request: ServerRequest) = RESPONSE
```

The RESPONSE is the following object --

```kotlin
val RESPONSE = ServerResponse
            .ok()
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(""" {"status":"success"}"""))
```

Full stack trace -

```
2020-07-28 10:56:44.148 ERROR 23680 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [cd98df7e-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/dmm/health"

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.java:220) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/dmm/health" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.java:220) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.prepareAttributeMono(ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.java:170) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.java:117) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:123) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:201) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.lambda$handle$1(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:199) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:153) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:274) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:851) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:173) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2344) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:132) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2152) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2026) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:145) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4219) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:441) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:211) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:161) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4219) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerHandle.onStateChange(HttpServerHandle.java:64) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:514) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServerBind$ChildObserver.onStateChange(TcpServerBind.java:267) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:465) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:96) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:170) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) ~[netty-codec-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3427) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2631) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.java:217) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.prepareAttributeMono(ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.java:170) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.java:117) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:123) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:201) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.lambda$handle$1(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:199) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:153) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:274) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:851) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:173) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2344) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:132) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2152) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2026) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:145) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4219) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:441) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:211) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:161) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4219) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerHandle.onStateChange(HttpServerHandle.java:64) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:514) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServerBind$ChildObserver.onStateChange(TcpServerBind.java:267) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:465) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:96) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:170) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) ~[netty-codec-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: You either use functional style or not. You are combining both functional and traditional that isn't going to work. Remove the annotations and use the functional way of registering this function. \

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you use the `@GetMapping` annotation with a functional endpoint. However, this annotation is intended for annotated controllers only. Annotated controllers and functional endpoints are two different approaches that you usually don't want to combine.

To map a functional endpoint to a URL, use the Coroutines router DSL, something like:

```kotlin
val route = coRouter { 
    accept(APPLICATION_JSON).nest {
        GET("/dmm/health", handler::dmmHealth)
    }
}
```

Check out more info on the functional endpoints in the [Spring WebFlux documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn).

Comment: Thank you.... 
Moving to the functional DSL based endpoint worked !

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else ending up here; instead of what @Sergei suggests to use the functional API, you could also replace the `ServerRequest` argument with `ServerHttpRequest`, which is supported with the `@GetMapping` annotation.

This does require the use of `ResponseEntity` as opposed to `ServerResponse`.

So that would become something like:

```
@GetMapping(value = ["/dmm/health"], produces = arrayOf(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
fun dmmHealth(request: ServerHttpRequest) = ResponseEntity
        .ok()
        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
        .body("""{"status":"success"}""")
```