# Spring Webflux - HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

Tags: java, spring-webclient

Can you please advise why I am getting error Resolved `[org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]`. It's a simple spring webflux contoller.

```
@RestController
public class TestContoller {

    @GetMapping("/Test")
    public Mono<ServerResponse> handleRequest2() {
        return
                Mono.just("Hello")
                        .flatMap(s -> ServerResponse.ok()
                                .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                                .bodyValue(s))
                        .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.just("Hello, Stranger")
                                .flatMap(s -> ServerResponse.ok()
                                        .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                                        .bodyValue(s)));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got a clue from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63134334/no-primary-or-default-constructor-found-for-interface-org-springframework-web-re). Need to use functional endpoints instead of `@GetMapping` for `ServerRequest` and `ServerResponse` object to work correctly.

Sample Router Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class RouterConfig {

private KeyConversionHandler handler;

public RouterConfig(KeyConversionHandler handler) {
    this.handler = handler;
}

@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routerFunctions() {
    return RouterFunctions.route().GET("/productGroup/{displayId}", handler::getProductGroupId).build();
}
}
```

Sample Handler Configuration:

```
@Service    
public class KeyConversionHandler {

    private KeyConversionService keyConversionService;

    public KeyConversionHandler(KeyConversionService keyConversionService) {
        this.keyConversionService = keyConversionService;
    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> getProductGroupId(ServerRequest request){

        String displayId = request.pathVariable("displayId");
        String token= request.headers().firstHeader(X_SAP_CRM_TOKEN);
        return keyConversionService.getProductGroupId(displayId,token)
                .flatMap(s-> ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(s))
                .onErrorResume(e -> ServerResponse.status(500).bodyValue(e.getLocalizedMessage()))
                .log();
    }
}
```